# What's the definition for real estate in neighbourhoods that add value to people’s societal activities and social life?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In Dutch we know 'Maatschappelijk Vastgoed' but I can't find the right translation to English. If the phenomenon even exists at all in other countries. I'm looking for a word that summarizes the following: *real estate in neighbourhoods that add value to people’s societal activities and social life, to residents and others, that is paid or sponsored by government, regardless who or what kind of organization or enterprise handles or possesses it*.

Comment: Are you referring to a [*community centre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_centre)?

Comment: A simple Google Translate gives *Social Real Estate*. We may have to coin a new word in English that will encapsulate the definition!

Comment: Thank you! Than maybe it should be societal real estate..? Or do you think social real estate fits best?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are looking for a verb, noun or adjective. But some residential areas have *a good social infrastructure*, others do not. The other day I was in the old London Docklands, which in recent decades have been converted to residential zones with easy access to Central London. The architectural ambience, retaining the old with the new is excellent. But the residences are effectively just dormitories - the social infrastructure that one notices - schools, churches, sports clubs, neighbourhood shops, etc - in traditional residential parts of London seem absent.

Comment: Thanks to you too Lawrence, that might come close! It surely covers a part of the definition. However, I'm not sure whether it is completely what I mean.. Food for thought, great!

Comment: I think it has to be a noun or adjective, WS2. It is about real estate, but a special kind of real estate that is available for society, regardless whether or not they are organized in some way and regardless of ownership. For example, churches, theaters, community centers, estate with cultural and historical value, schools, vaccination centers, etc

Comment: Could you mean "community institutions"? "public venues"? "Public spaces"? "Social centers"? The Third Place? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place

Comment: @Annette FYI, where we come from, the government doesn't sponsor them :-\

Comment: @Annette You might also want to check this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Urban_studies_and_planning_terminology

Comment: The "paid [for] or sponsored by government,regardless [of] who or what kind of organization or enterprise handles or possesses it" is at the heart of the difficulty here.  And how can a *church* be an example of this?

Comment: In the US, we have sports stadiums whose construction is funded largely by taxpayers, even though private owners of the teams which play in them make billions of dollars of profit. Americans like professional sports so much that we don't mind spending $8.50 for a 12 ounce cup of beer and $5 for a hot dog. The minimum wage in Pennsylvania is $7.25 per hour, to put those prices in some perspective. The average ticket price is over $200. Would you consider such stadiums and their public funding an example?

Comment: Tax law renders this a nonstarter in most locations. The government wants the real estate taxes. And the government can't take depreciation on it's possessions. Which is why sports stadiums, airports, and bridges are now commonly corporate possessions. On a small scale, there is still some opportunity for [public spaces](https://www.pps.org/about)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word 'amenities'?
"The neighborhood includes amenities such as a playground and walking trails."

> a·men·i·ty
>
> əˈmenədē/
>
> noun
>
> plural noun: amenities
>
> a desirable or useful feature or facility of a building or place.
> "heating is regarded as a basic amenity"